# How to make function useable only for a certain data constructor of an ADT?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types, option-type, undefined-function

I'm currently playing around with ADTs in Haskell and try to build an ADT `Figure`:

```
data Figure = Rect { x :: Integer, y :: Integer, width :: Integer, height :: Integer}
            | Circle { x :: Integer, y :: Integer, radius :: Integer}
            | CombiFigure Figure Figure
            deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

Now I came across the question how to implement a function that should not accept every `Figure`, but e.g. only a `Circle`.

Do I already have a bad design? Or is there some best-practice how to do this?

As example, think about a diameter function. All that came to my mind (I'm a complete beginner in Haskell) are the following two options, using `undefined` or `Maybe`:

1:

```
diameter :: Figure -> Integer
diameter (Circle _ _ r) = 2 * r
diameter _ = undefined
```

2:

```
diameter :: Figure -> Maybe Integer
diameter (Circle _ _ r) = Just (2 * r)
diameter _ = Nothing
```

Are there more preferable ways on how to accomplish that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that there is something not right here. The best way of thinking about it would be to start at the function `diameter` and decide what it's type should ideally be. You would likely come up with

```
diameter :: Circle -> Integer
diameter (Circle _ _ r) = 2 * r
```

because diameters are only defined for circles.

This means that you will have to augment your data structure by splitting out Circle (and Rect too):

```
data Figure = RectFigure Rect
            | CircleFigure Circle
            | CombiFigure Figure Figure
            deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

data Rect = Rect { rectX :: Integer, rectY :: Integer, rectWidth :: Integer, height :: Integer}
          deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

data Circle = Circle { circleX :: Integer, circleY :: Integer, circleRadius :: Integer}
            deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
```

which is nice because it is now more flexible: you can write functions that don't care what `Figure` they are applied to, *and* you can write functions that are defined on specific `Figure`s.

Now, if we are in a higher-up function and have a reference to a `Figure` and we want to compute its `diameter` *if* it's a `CircleFigure`, then you can use pattern matching to do this.

Note: using `undefined` or exceptions (in pure code) is likely a code smell. It could probably be solved by rethinking your types. If you have to indicate failure, then use `Maybe`/`Either`.

Comment: this will fail to compile because of multiple definitions of `x` and `y` field labels (until [`DuplicateRecordFields`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/DuplicateRecordFields) is landed)

Comment: Another option is to use `data PlacedFigure = PlacedFigure { x :: Integer, y :: Integer, figure :: Figure }`. This extracts the common feature of figure placement. It's not as efficient, perhaps, but that's usually fine.

Comment: True, and going more generic would be something like `data WithPlacement a = WithPlacement { x :: Integer, y :: Integer, placed :: a }`.

Answer (score 3):

Your type definition by itself (i.e `data Figure = ...`) is introducing [partial functions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Avoiding_partial_functions). e.g. even though `width` is of type `width :: Figure -> Integer` it can only work on `Rect` values:

```
\> width $ Rect 1 2 3 4
3
\> width $ Circle 1 2 3 
*** Exception: No match in record selector width
```

so, you already have defined functions which can work on one figure but not another (similar to `diameter` function in the question).

That said, a 3rd solution would be to define `Circle`, `Rectangle` etc, as separate types; then, define a `Figure` [type class](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types) which defines the *common interface* of these types.

```
class Figure a where
    area, perimeter :: a -> Double

instance Figure Circle where
    area = ...
    perimeter = ...
```

Additionally each type may have their own exclusive functions. Or, you may add more interfaces, (i.e. type classes) which cover some but not all the figure types.

An advantage of type classes is that *they are easier to extend*; e.g. if one wants to add, say, a `Triangle` type later on, he can *opt-in* any type class which applies to a triangle, and define an instance only for those type classes.

Whereas in the `data Figure = ...` approach, you need to find every function which can take a `Figure` as argument and make sure it will handle a `Triangle` as well. If you are shipping a library then you do not have access to all these functions.

<sub>>> for the reference, there was a similar recent discussion of [data declaration vs type classes](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2016-January/thread.html#122671) on haskell cafe mailing list.</sub>